# Incorrect display of TEXT in SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

**The code that generates SVG:**

```
"<text x=\"" + (Width / 2) + "\" y=\"18\" width=\"30\" text-anchor=\"middle\" font-weight=\"Bold\" font-family=\"Simplex\" font-size=\"7\">" + "123" + "</text>"
```

**The code is looped so it displays repeatedly**
[image]

What's wrong with this text?

Conclusions:

- centers the first digit
- other elements start at the beginning of the element

When I remove the `text-anchor`, it changes a little but it still displays incorrectly

Comment: you don't need a width for the text but your code is working correctly for me. Please try adding a working example reproducing your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably division by 2 `(Width / 2)`

You get a floating point value, which means that the separator is `,` instead of `.` in String Value

Use:

```
(Width / 2).ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```